# How to include every option of CHOICE command in BAT file in a new line?

Tags: batch-file

I want to put every option of CHOICE command in a  new line.

e.g

```
CHOICE /N /C:123 /M "1 - one \n 2 - two \n 3 - three"
```

but this gives me the prompt: 1 - one \n 2 - two \n 3 - three

How can I put these options shown on the prompt in different lines ? Like this:

```
1 - one  
2 - two  
3 - three
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo 1 - one
echo 2 - two
echo 3 - three
choice /n /c:123
```

Quite simple, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @Joey, How can I use this in congestion with `set /P choice =`

Would grateful for any idea.